# regex to grab simple path out of a string?

Tags: regex, filepath

I have a string: `GET public/hello.txt HTTP/1.1`

and I'm trying to capture `public/hello.txt`.

This is what I have tried so far: `(?<=GET ).+\\/[^\\.]+\\.[^ ]+(?!=(HTTP\\/1.1))`

Is there a better way to do this?

edit: 
tried `(?<=GET )(.+)(?= HTTP\\/1.1)`

compiled in Java, and matcher returns no groups.

Comment: Your regex seems overcomplicated for what you need. `GET ([^ ]+) HTTP\/1.1` should also works.

Comment: Why not a simpler `^GET (\S+)`?

Comment: Split the string at the space, take the second part. There's no need for regex here.

Comment: [It does](http://ideone.com/6xXNAz)

Comment: I wasn't calling matcher.find(). I feel so embarrassed. Thanks!

Comment: You do not need any `Matcher`s in Java, just use `.replace("GET ", "").replace(" HTTP/1.1", "")`. Or `.split("\\s+")` and get the item[1].

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
(?<=GET )(.+)(?= HTTP\/1.1)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nZ9dK2/1) or [live java](http://ideone.com/6xXNAz)

Answer (score 1):

as the start and end is mostly the same, this should split it up in 3 parts

`/(GET|POST) (.*) HTTP\/1.[01]/`